# Google map showing gray tiles only on android studio

Tags: android, api, google-maps, dictionary, key

I am created a new android project with a google map activity. my activity code is:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));
}
```

}

and this is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!--
     The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
     location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality.
-->

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="xxxxxx.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permisson.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-permission android:name="xxxxx.mapservice.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="xxxxx.provides.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<permission android:name="xxxxx.mapservice.permission.MAPS_RECIEVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <!--
         The API key for Google Maps-based APIs is defined as a string resource.
         (See the file "res/values/google_maps_api.xml").
         Note that the API key is linked to the encryption key used to sign the APK.
         You need a different API key for each encryption key, including the release key that is used to
         sign the APK for publishing.
         You can define the keys for the debug and release targets in src/debug/ and src/release/. 
    -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and I got an google Api key and restrict it with sh1 key. I followed google documentation but unfortunately my map is not loading.

While I am searching some comments suggesting that I should delete the debug.keystore but this is not working for me. What am I missing?

Also my map layout xml file is:

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.iuwa.testmap.MapsActivity" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this into your manifest outside of application tag and check

```
<uses-feature
android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
android:required="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution!
My wrong was in generating correct sha1 code. Previously, I found this key using gradle menu in right side of android studio using following procedure:first clicking on gradle and then, under app, Tasks, android, I clicked on signingReport:

[image]

then the sha1 appeared in gradle console:

[image]

My falut was that this code is for debug mode!
I followed the below procedure to get sha1 release for my release keystore and after entering this new sha1 in google developer console my map appears completely. 
To get sha1 release, first you should copy your release keystore address:
go to build >> generateSigendApk and copy your key store path.

[image]

then you should copy the path of your jdk that android studio uses. Go to File>> ProjectStructure and you can see your jdk path. copy this path and in cmd go to this folder.

[image]

Then cd yor jdk and then bin folder and copy the following line:
keytool -list -v -keystore "YOUR COPIED KEY STORE PATH" -alias "KEY ALIAS"
Now enter and enjoy your release sha1 code :)